# MySQL riddle with subquery

Tags: mysql

EDIT: looks like an index issue, update at the bottom of the question

I have the following query + subquery whose results I cannot explain. I am starting with this minimal input data set (the application here is capturing data change, and the PK is the `id` + the `tx_id`).

```
mysql> select * from tag_version;
+----+-------------------+------------+-------+----------------+
| id | name              | article_id | tx_id | operation_type |
+----+-------------------+------------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | some tag          |          1 |     1 |              0 |
|  1 | updated tag       |          1 |     2 |              1 |
|  1 | updated again tag |          1 |     3 |              1 |
|  2 | other tag         |          1 |     2 |              0 |
+----+-------------------+------------+-------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The subquery, standalone

```
SELECT max(f.tx_id) as max_tx_id, f.id
from tag_version f
WHERE f.tx_id <= 2
GROUP BY f.id
```

Result is

```
+-----------+----+
| max_tx_id | id |
+-----------+----+
|         2 |  1 |
|         2 |  2 |
+-----------+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query, where I manually inject the subquery results, notice how they are equal to the above

```
select t.*
from tag_version t
where t.article_id = 1
AND (t.tx_id, t.id) IN (
    (2,1),
    (2,2)
)
```

With expected results

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------+
| id | name        | article_id | tx_id | operation_type |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | updated tag |          1 |     2 |              1 |
|  2 | other tag   |          1 |     2 |              0 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And lastly, using the subquery in place of the tuples...

```
select t.*
from tag_version t
where t.article_id = 1
AND (t.tx_id, t.id) IN (
    SELECT max(f.tx_id) as tx_id, f.id
    from tag_version f
    WHERE f.tx_id <= 2
    GROUP BY f.id
)
```

The result is `Empty set (0.00 sec)`! Can someone explain this? I get the same empty results when I re-write the query using `EXISTS` instead of `IN`

I noticed than when I remove the line `WHERE f.tx_id <= 2` from the subquery, I actually get results (although the wrong ones):

```
+----+-------------------+------------+-------+----------------+
| id | name              | article_id | tx_id | operation_type |
+----+-------------------+------------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | updated again tag |          1 |     3 |              1 |
|  2 | other tag         |          1 |     2 |              0 |
+----+-------------------+------------+-------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Replacing the subquery with a `JOIN` actually returns the expected correct results

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tag_version t
JOIN (
    SELECT max(f.tx_id) as max_tx_id, f.id
    from tag_version f
    WHERE f.tx_id <= 2
    GROUP BY f.id
) as max_ids
ON max_ids.max_tx_id = t.tx_id
AND max_ids.id = t.id
where t.article_id = 1
```

Result:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------+
| id | name        | article_id | tx_id | operation_type |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | updated tag |          1 |     2 |              1 |
|  2 | other tag   |          1 |     2 |              0 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In addition, running the same query+subquery on the same data set with both PostgreSQL and SQLite gives the expected correct results.

My MySQL version is `Server version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)`.

I think the clue to figuring out what's happening is that I actually get results when I remove the `WHERE` from the subquery, but I can't make something useful out of it.

EDIT: updated with input data set

EDIT: add table information

The table create statement is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_version` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tx_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `operation_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`tx_id`),
  KEY `ix_tag_version_operation_type` (`operation_type`),
  KEY `ix_tag_version_tx_id` (`tx_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data population as well

```
insert into tag_version (id, name, article_id, tx_id, operation_type) VALUES 
(1, 'some tag', 1, 1, 0),
(1, 'updated tag', 1, 2, 1),
(1, 'updated again tag', 1, 3, 1),
(2, 'other tag', 1, 2, 0)
;
```

When I remove the `ix_tag_version_tx_id` index, the query returns the correct results... An explanation of why would be useful.

Comment: Can you show some sample input data?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you join with the subquery instead of using `IN`?

Comment: I updated my question with sample input data, and the query re-written with a `JOIN`. I would really like to find out which MySQL feature results in the unexpected (to me) results when using the subquery.

Comment: Maybe a MySQL bug -- I can't reproduce it with MySQL 5.1.73. Are there any indexes on the table?

Comment: Yes, it looks like an index problem.

Comment: Please post `show create table tag_version` so we can try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you made a mistake in showing the result of first code(subquery).

The output of this query:

```
SELECT max(f.tx_id) as qwer, f.id
from tag_version f
WHERE f.tx_id <= 2
GROUP BY f.id
```

-is not:

```
+--------------+----+
| max(f.tx_id) | id |
+--------------+----+
|            2 |  1 |
|            2 |  2 |
+--------------+----+
```

It is:

```
+------+----+
| qwer | id |
+------+----+
|   2  |  1 |
|   2  |  2 |
+------+----+
```

(*Notice: the code line `max(f.tx_id) as qwer` *)

Now try this code for the expexted output.
There is a change when selecting `max(f.tx_id)`.

```
select t.*
from tag_version t
where t.`article_id` = 1
AND t.`operation_type` != 2
AND (t.`tx_id`, t.`id`) IN (
    SELECT max(f.`tx_id`) as `tx_id`, f.`id`
    from tag_version f
    WHERE f.`tx_id` <= 2
    GROUP BY f.`id`
)
```

Let me know if this gives you the result or any other error.

Comment: Unfortunately this was not it, renaming the column in the sub-select has no effect on the result (I tried your `tx_id` rename as well). I updated my answer with a trivial input data set that demonstrates the problem.